# Can the third person pronoun "they" be used to refer to the singular gender-neutral pronoun "one"?

Tags: grammar, pronouns, grammatical-gender, gender-neutral

For instance, would it be correct to say "One must be careful so that they do not lose control of the vehicle while driving in heavy snow"?
I think I have read similar phrases before but I can't find any examples online at the moment. Links to similar examples would be of utmost help! Thank you so much!

Comment: It seems clumsy next to "One must be careful *not to* lose control of the vehicle *when* driving in heavy snow."

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use the same pronoun: "One must be careful so that one does not lose control of the vehicle while driving in heavy snow"? There's a slight ambiguity in "One must be careful so that they do not lose control of the vehicle while driving in heavy snow", in that "one" and "they" need not refer to the same thing, but often the meaning will be clear.

Comment: @WeatherVane I don't think too many people would use *when* there. *While* is used for two continuous (and unending) actions like being careful while driving in the snow. Some might use *when* for a long-duration action with an implied end, like being careful when driving home. In Ngrams, "while driving" beats "when driving" 7 to 2. And there are different constructions that do take "when driving" so the ratio is probably a lot higher for this construction.

Comment: @PhilSweet I would say it depends on the context. "It is dangerous to smoke while driving", or "It is dangerous to be inattentive when driving."